# How to phrase indirect commands with pedir

Tags: gramática

What's the difference and/or which is better?

1. pedir para eles pararem
2. pedir para que eles parassem
3. pedir que eles parassem

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is tense (also aspect, mood) itself

In the first example, *pararem* in an inflected infinitive.
The sentence means "ask them to stop".

In the two last sentences, *parassem* is a present subjunctive, meaning a condition. The difference between these two is how you use the verb *pedir* — the same way that in english you can "ask *something*" and "ask **for** *something*", you can do in portuguese, "pedir *alguma coisa*" and "pedir **para** *alguma coisa", you cam even "pedir **por** *alguma coisa*". It's just a matter of what compliment is the verb asking for.

Answer (score 1):

There is essentially no difference in your examples, at least without any other context.

I can't think of any situation where *pedir que* can't be replaced with *pedir para* or the rarer *pedir para que*.

However, *pedir para* may not be interchangeable with *pedir que*.

Consider these two sentences:

> (1) O João não fez o que pai lhe pediu para evitar o contágio.
>   (2) O João pediu para ir à rua.

In (1), *para* introduces the purpose/intention of the request, not the content of the request; *para* has here a strong lexical component. (incidentally, the sentence is also ambiguous, and *para* can also introduce the reason João didn't do what was asked of him)

In (2), we have a different predicate. *Pedir para* here means *ask for*, somewhat equivalent to:

> (3) O João pediu que o deixassem ir à rua.

Another example, where it's a request not involving permission:

> (4) Foi o próprio Presidente a pedir para reunir com todas as pessoas atingidas pela catástrofe.